# STARTTLS error when sending mail through XAMPP

Tags: email, xampp, smtp, phpmailer, tls1.2

I'm working on a website that has a form which sends an email upon submission using XAMPP. Unfortunately I can't seem to get rid of the error

```
Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. g20-20020a17090a7d1400b001fd674057d2sm3458984pjl.48 - gsmtp in C:\xampp\htdocs\contact.php on line 25
```

here are my ini files

php.ini

```
[mail function]

SMTP=smtp.gmail.com

smtp_port=587


sendmail_from = ***@gmail.com


;sendmail_path =


;mail.force_extra_parameters =


mail.add_x_header=Off

mail.log = "C:\xampp\mailoutput\mail.log"
```

sendmail.ini

```
[sendmail]


smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com


smtp_port=587


smtp_ssl=tls


;default_domain=mydomain.com


error_logfile=error.log


;debug_logfile=debug.log


auth_username=***@gmail.com
auth_password=***


pop3_server=pop.gmail.com
pop3_username=***@gmail
pop3_password=***


force_sender=***@gmail.com


force_recipient=


hostname=smtp.gmail.com
```

I've tried changing SMTP to tls://smtp.gmail.com which threw an error that it couldnt connect, then I tried ssl://smtp.gmail.com and changed the port to 465 and I got the same error. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed it by changing sendmail_path to
`sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"` which got rid of the warning. Unfortunately though I can't find the email anywhere in my inbox. Any help with this would be appreciated!